# metodos dentro de los objetos de la clase funcion en javascript

Tags: javascript, phaser.io

Estoy tratando de aprender un framework de html5 para desarrollo videojuegos, llamado phaser, por lo que me encuentro realizado el tutorial de [aqui](http://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part2), donde dice 'Loading Assets' hay una función `preload` que carga las imágenes o assets comunmente llamados 'assets' del juego, el código de la función es este:

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('sky', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/sky.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/platform.png');
    this.load.image('star', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/star.png');
    this.load.image('bomb', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/bomb.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('dude', 
        'src/games/firstgame/assets/dude.png',
        { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
}
```

lo que me llama la atención de esto es que dentro de las líneas del código de la función se llama a un parametro o método `load`, y luego `image` se que las funciones dentro de Javascript son objetos por lo que la sentencia `this` referencia al mismo objeto función en este caso `preload`. Intenté buscar algún tipo de documentación de este método o parametro `load` para saber si es algún tipo de objeto definido en Javascript pero no encontre nada, **me gustaría entender porque se puede escribir lo que se muestra en la función** ya que pienso que no es un método definido dentro de la clase Function de Javascript

Comment: Hasta donde sé load no existe nativamente en javascript (que alguien me corrija de no ser así) sin embargo si existe en librerías como jquery por ejemplo. Probablemente el load que estás observando sea una función diseñada por los creadores del framework "Phaser". Siendo Javascript con lo que estás trabajando sería un poco más apropiado que uses el término función en vez de objeto.

Comment: entiendo, en este caso entonces cual sería el contexto de la setencia `this` o no es posible saberlo a simple vista?

Comment: Con "contexto" preguntas si es global o local la referencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este método preload esta dentro de un objeto que extiende de Phaser.State, el cual contiene el objeto load (Phaser.Loader) que es el que tu llamas para cargar assets en el juego te dejo la documentación oficial.

Documentación Phaser.State:
https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.State.html

Documentación Phaser.State.load
https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.State.html#load

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones en javascript son ejecutadas con un contexto para `this` determinado.

En scripts webs por lo general this corresponde al objeto `window`, pero uno podría realizar lo siguiente:

```
function miFuncion(){
    this.a = 1;
}

var obj = {};
miFuncion.call(obj);
console.log(obj); // imprime {a: 1}
```

Efectivamente especificando el contexto para `this`

Answer (score -1):

Cuando usas Phaser, la forma de trabajar es crear un objeto [`Game`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Game.html) y pasarle, entre otros atributos, el objeto `State`, que debe/puede tener los métodos preload, create, update, render. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
function preload() { ... }

function create() { ... }

let game= new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', 
{ preload: preload, create: create });
```

Lo que hace Phaser internamente es algo como esto:

```
//this es la instancia de Game
var preload=this.state.preload;
preload();
```

Por tanto, `this` es una instancia de `Phaser.Game`, que tiene [las propiedades que estás usando](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Game.html#members).

Si declarases preload así:

```
let preload= () => {


};
```

Podrías comprobar como el juego falla, porque las funciones arrow tienen el contexto fijado en tiempo de declaración.